# Create a file as one user and edit it as another user

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, chmod

Im writing a shell to automate a process this shell will be run as root or as another user but not as the postgres user (meaning the user will just run the script)

What i did as a postgres user while testing was

```
touch /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf
sudo nano recovery.conf (wrote some content )
ctrl +O
```

However whenever I try to do this by using the following lines in my shell as as another user (including root)

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "touch /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf"
```

The file is created as postgres user which is what i intended, and then i run

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c echo "content" > /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf
```

and get a

```
-bash: /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf: Permission denied
```

How come I can create the file but not put content on it?

I already tried giving 775 and 777 permisions using chmod

```
chmod 775 recovery.conf
```

as the psotgres user and i get

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 postgres postgres  133 May 11 22:11 recovery.conf
```

to this file as a postgres user and still the error persists so  im confused about whats going on

Answer (score 0):

At the second line where you try to put the "echo" command, please use:

```
/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf
```

With a / at the beginning

Comment: wel thats embarassing, now at least i can find the file, yet, now the problem is that i cant write it  `-bash: /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf: Permission denied
` even after running a chmod 775 recovery.conf as the psotgres user

Comment: I would do it differently, perhaps you should try , if applies :    echo "content" | sudo postgres -a /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf.  For more information, I think this article resumes it pretty fine: https://www.networkworld.com/article/3322504/selectively-deploying-your-superpowers-on-linux.html